# If $A^2 = I$, then $A$ is elementary?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is of size $n{\times}n$.

Is it true or false? I'm trying to think of a counter example but fail to do so.

Comment: Consider an antidiagonal matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by "elementary"?

Comment: @Math1000 If I take I and make one change to it (one row change of any kind) then the new matrix is elementary